# Move element to the end of parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML in my application:

```
    <div class="work-item">
        <div class="image-container">                
        </div>
        <div class="text-container">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="work-item">
        <div class="text-container">                
        </div>
        <div class="image-container">                
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="work-item">
        <div class="image-container">                
        </div>
        <div class="text-container">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="work-item">
        <div class="text-container">                
        </div>
        <div class="image-container">                
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'd like to take any element that has class `text-container`, and if it's the first element under `work-item`, move it after the div with class `image-container`, so that every div element looks like

```
    <div class="work-item">
        <div class="image-container">                
        </div>
        <div class="text-container">
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried just removing it first with this:

```
$(".work-item .text-container:first-child").remove();
```

And that worked fine, but when I tried to move it with this, it didn't work at all, nothing happened:

```
$("#work .work-item .text-container:first-child").insertAfter($(this).parent()["last-child"]);
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this:

```js
$('.text-container').each(function(index, item) {
    var $this = $(item);
    $this.appendTo($this.parent());
});
```

```css
.work-item{
    margin:20px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="work-item">
    <div class="image-container">img              
    </div>
    <div class="text-container">txt
    </div>
</div>

<div class="work-item">
    <div class="text-container">txt             
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">img           
    </div>
</div>

<div class="work-item">
    <div class="image-container">img        
    </div>
    <div class="text-container">txt
    </div>
</div>

<div class="work-item">
    <div class="text-container">txt             
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">img           
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way, where you save the parent element as a variable

```
var theParent = $(".work-item .text-container:first-child").parent();

$(".work-item .text-container:first-child").detach().appendTo(theParent);
```

and then use detach instead of remove, so that it still saves the info in memory, and then append it to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

just use `insertAfter` can achieve your purpose.
This is my [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/q32v3epr/2/)

```
var text = $('.text-container');
var img = $('.image-container');
text.insertAfter(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(".work-item .text-container:nth-child(1)").each(function () {
    var elm = $(this);
    if (elm.next().is($(".image-container"))) {
         var parent = elm.parent();
         parent.append(elm.detach());
    }

});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pkpL6101/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Because, The first element may be “.text-container” or ".image-container".

If the first element is ".image-container".

```
$("#work .work-item .text-container:first-child").length == 0;
```

So you get the first element is not correct.

This is my:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var workItems = $(".work-item");

 var len = workItems.length,i = 0,el,first;
 for(;i < len; i++){
  el = workItems[i];
  first = $(el).children().first();
  if (first.hasClass("text-container")){
   $(el).append(first);
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="work-item">
    <div class="image-container">img              
    </div>
    <div class="text-container">txt
    </div>
</div>

<div class="work-item">
    <div class="text-container">txt             
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">img           
    </div>
</div>

<div class="work-item">
    <div class="image-container">img        
    </div>
    <div class="text-container">txt
    </div>
</div>

<div class="work-item">
    <div class="text-container">txt             
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">img           
    </div>
</div>
```